# How to extract lat/long placemark.coordinate in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I added a location search bar to my app. The tableview controller consists of the user location lat/long as well as the destination (address the user inputs into the search bar).  As far as I can tell the latitude / longitude is within the placemark.coordinate:

```
placemark.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 45.253519203737767, longitude: -66.070974382763978)
```

I have two variables: **destLat** and **destLong**.  How I can extract the latitude and longitude from placemark.coordinate and place into the two variables mentioned above?

**related code:**

```
// cache the pin
    selectedPin = placemark

    // clear existing pins
    mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = placemark.coordinate
    annotation.title = placemark.name
    if let city = placemark.locality,
        let prov = placemark.administrativeArea {
        annotation.subtitle = "\(city), \(prov)"
    }

    let destination = placemark.coordinate
    print("Destination coordinates: \(destination)")
    let name = placemark.name
    print("Placemark Name: \(name!)")


    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(placemark.coordinate, span)
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
```

**Console output:**

[image]

Comment: Taking a look over this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24706885/how-can-i-plot-addresses-in-swift-converting-address-to-longitude-and-latitude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps your were thinking too hard. You can assign values to these variables just like any other:

```
let (destLat, destLong) = (placemark.coordinate.latitude, placemark.coordinate.longitude)
```

Answer (score 1):

If both variable you have declare is type of `Double` then you need to simply need to access the `latitude` and `longitude` property of `CLLocationCoordinate2D`.

```
destLat = destination.latitude
destLong = destination.longitude
```

If type of both var is different then simply change it to `Double` works for you.